# Serializing anonymous functions in php

Tags: php, serialization, anonymous-function

is there any way to serialize an anonymous function in php?

i have found this http://www.htmlist.com/development/extending-php-5-3-closures-with-serialization-and-reflection/

```
protected function _fetchCode()
{
    // Open file and seek to the first line of the closure
    $file = new SplFileObject($this->reflection->getFileName());
    $file->seek($this->reflection->getStartLine()-1);

    // Retrieve all of the lines that contain code for the closure
    $code = '';
    while ($file->key() < $this->reflection->getEndLine())
    {
        $code .= $file->current();
        $file->next();
    }

    // Only keep the code defining that closure
    $begin = strpos($code, 'function');
    $end = strrpos($code, '}');
    $code = substr($code, $begin, $end - $begin + 1);

    return $code;
}
```

but it depends on the internal implementation of closure.

are there any future plans to implement closure serialization?

Comment: You want at some point to pass PHP-function to PHP? Why?

Comment: suppose i have some ui component library, and i want to give the user some degree of customization in the output(through anon functions). and that i want to be able to recharge the save the state of the object in the session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734224/exception-serialization-of-closure-is-not-allowed)

Comment: If the accepted answer to the question is simply a link to the answer of another question, then the question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Get string representation of anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308365/get-string-representation-of-anonymous-function)

https://3v4l.org/CEmqV

UPDATE PHP8

```
<?php

function closure_to_str($func)
{
    $refl = new \ReflectionFunction($func); // get reflection object
    $path = $refl->getFileName();  // absolute path of php file
    $begn = $refl->getStartLine(); // have to `-1` for array index
    $endn = $refl->getEndLine();
    $dlim = PHP_EOL;
    $list = explode($dlim, file_get_contents($path));         // lines of php-file source
    $list = array_slice($list, ($begn-1), ($endn-($begn-1))); // lines of closure definition
    $last = (count($list)-1); // last line number

    if((substr_count($list[0],'function')>1)|| (substr_count($list[0],'{')>1) || (substr_count($list[$last],'}')>1))
    { throw new \Exception("Too complex context definition in: `$path`. Check lines: $begn & $endn."); }

    $list[0] = ('function'.explode('function',$list[0])[1]);
    $list[$last] = (explode('}',$list[$last])[0].'}');


    return implode($dlim,$list);
}

$dog2 = function(){ 
    return 'test';
};

echo closure_to_str($dog2)."\n\n";
```

Return String

```
function(){ 
    return 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look to my response here about PHP Super Closure :

[Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734224/exception-serialization-of-closure-is-not-allowed/19730234#19730234)

I hope it helps.