# Get string representation of anonymous function

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

Let's say I have an anonymous PHP function like this:

```
<?php
$l = function() { echo "hello world"; };
```

Is it possible to get a string representation of the anonymous function `$l`, i.e. a string containing the function body?

I tried a few things:

- `echo $l;` PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Closure could not be converted to string
- `var_dump($l);` class Closure#1 (0) { }
- `echo $l->__toString();`: Call to undefined method Closure::__toString()
- `get_class_methods($l)` returns `array('bind', 'bindTo')`, so it seems like no undocumented methods exist
- `$r = new ReflectionClass($l);`:  getProperties(), getConstants() and getStaticProperties() are all empty, also `$r->__toString()` does not return anything useful.

I don't really need this in my code, I just thought it might be useful for logging purposes if something goes wrong. After I couldn't come up with a solution by myself I am curious if it is possible at all.

Comment: What do you think about `create_function()` so that you can have the function content as string and just need to name it something through this function?

Comment: @Javad that's a good idea. However, I'd like to pass the anonymous function as a method parameter. Sure I could simply pass a string and the method's parameters instead and use `create_function()`, but then the syntax will be checked only at runtime, which kind of contradicts the idea of anonymous functions.

Comment: Yes you are right, but if you check the manual for `create_function()` you can create an anonymous function by this [http://ca1.php.net/create_function] (Check first Example)

Comment: No. Closures are compiled at runtime like any other piece of code. The only way around this is to store the function body as a string and use `create_function()` as @Javad has already stated.

Answer (score 4):

Your only "real" option is to use an actual [PHP parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) to parse the anonymous function.

Don't fall in [the same trap as @argon did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45226440/508666) thinking a simple `substr_count` based script can actually parse PHP code. It's just too brittle and will break even for the most simple examples in glorious ways.

Point in case:

```
$dog2 = ['bark'=>function($foo = '{'){}];
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Too complex context definition in

https://3v4l.org/CEmqV

Comment: No need for expensive PHP parsing; if the source-code is too messy then it should be neatened up for readability. .. and your example above is unfair, why don't you simply edit the answer? too complicated for you?

Comment: How is the example above in any way "messy"?

Comment: see edited comment above @ fairness, look I can update the function to make it be "perfect" (for any closure - on one line) - but that would make it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, since no one has the time to comment or edit but only down-vote; you should be ashamed of yourself.

Answer (score -2):

Its an oxymoron to access the source code of an anonymous file. If you need to refer to the source, then don't create an anonymous function:

```
$myfunction='echo "hello world";';
$l = create_function($myfunction);
print highlight_string($myfunction) . " results in....<br />";
$l();
```

(hint, you might want to have a look at [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php))