# How to cache closures in php

Tags: php, arrays, caching, closures, callable

I want to cache an array which has also closures.

I've tried with:

- serialize() - *can't serialize closures*
- json_encode() - *replaces closure with empty value*
- base64_encode() - *doesn't accept arrays*

What else to do for caching array containing also closures ?

Comment: But closure serialization is not allowed by php "from the box". You can only use 3rd party libraries to reach your purpose. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php#113305

Comment: There is no native way to serialize closures. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734224/exception-serialization-of-closure-is-not-allowed/19730234#19730234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closures in PHP can not be serialized "from the box" hence array with closures too. You can only use 3rd party ways/libraries to reach this. 
Discussed here: [Serializing anonymous functions in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534245/serializing-anonymous-functions-in-php)