# Sharing complex objects across controller methods Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

Given the following scenario:

`controller@method_a` spawns a process (Symfony Process object) asynchronously, `controller@method_b` needs to interact with the process

How would you implement sharing the Process object?

Things I've went over:

- controller properties don't persist, as with each request the controller gets reinstantiated
- Session can't store complex objects, and serialization would take the soul of it
- database can't store complex objects either

---

**edit:**

To the serialization issue:

```
    $process = new Process("dir");
    $process->start();
    $x = serialize($process);
    dd($x);
```

If I remove the `$process->start()`, it does not fire `Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed`. But I can't do anything with a handle for a process that's not started.

Comment: If this is one controller, you can use public $var to hold data and share with another method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only option here is to [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) an object and persist it somewhere (DB, session, file). In next request, pull it and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: That fires a `Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed` exception.

Comment: Thanks. Check this asnwer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13734344/1227923 maybe it will give you some idea.