# Why don't serializate ActiveForm Object

Tags: php, serialization, yii2

I'm trying to serialize the Form object within a view so:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?php $largeString=serialize($form);   ?>
```

Because I always get the following error:

```
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

The PHP manual guarantees that you can seralize anything; What could be the problem?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734224/exception-serialization-of-closure-is-not-allowed)