# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed when using php's time()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, serialization, time

I keep running into:

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

when dispatching a Job in Laravel. I have narrowed down the culprit to PHP's `time()` function.

There is a function in my Job's that is causing this. I have debugged it down to these specifics:

**Causes error**

```
$this->myProp = time() + $someDelay;
```

**No error**:

```
$this->myProp = 123 + $someDelay;
```

Any help would be awesome :)

Comment: Have you tried with casting?: `$this->myProp = ((int) time()) + $someDelay;`

Comment: Yeah :\ doesn't help. I've printed out $this->myProp and it is the correctly computed value as an `int`.

Comment: Check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45997319/7117697) to see if this helps you.