# Serialization of Closure

Tags: php, serialization, closures

How can I fix this error?

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

This is my codes :

```php
class ST{
    private $Serial;

    public function __construct($F){
        $this->Serial = serialize($F);
    }
    public function Get(){
        return $this->Serial;
    }
}

$ST = new ST(function (){
    //echo "How Are You";
});

echo $ST->Get();
```

Comment: You can't fix it. It's just something PHP doesn't support. Why do you need to serialize a function?

Comment: Invoke the closure: `return serialize($F())`;

Comment: Take a look of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13734344/5177698). I hope this can helps