# Why can't serialize 'closure' for the first time only?

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, closures

Error is:

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Error at:

> .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php:295

Throws when remembering forever on Cache for the first time. 
After second try (when reloading browser) it works as it should work.

```php
public function cache() 
{
    $task = $this;

    return Cache::rememberForever('apply:' . $task->apply->slug . ':' . $task->slug, function () use ($task) {
        return $task;
    });
}
```

Interesting part is this. So it works on caching `$apply` on Apply's index page. (The code is the same)

**Note: This issue is related to Redis directly. Please don't mention old questions about serialization. You can check official Laravel 6.x documentation too. Everything is added related to it: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/cache#retrieving-items-from-the-cache**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734224/exception-serialization-of-closure-is-not-allowed)

Comment: No. It's related to Redis cache. I mentioned above

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe it has nothing to do with your Redis cache, but the fact that you are literally trying to serialize an anonymous function (a closure). Why do you need to wrap it in a function anyway, why can't you just cache `$task`?

Comment: because `rememberForever()`  only accepts callback function. Not variables

Comment: @James check this please: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/cache#retrieving-items-from-the-cache

Comment: Where does it say that? The docs literally say `Cache::forever(‘key’, ‘value’);`

Comment: Why are you trying the store a class in the cache? In the docs example they are using a collection. Your error is due to the fact that `$task` cannot be serialised. That’s a PHP limitation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202886/discussion-between-samir-mammadhasanov-and-james).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by manually storing and returning data if it exists on cache (how `rememberForever()` should be work).

```php
public function cache () {

    $slug = 'task:'.$this->slug;

    if(Cache::has($slug)) return Cache::get($slug);

    if(!Cache::put($slug, $this)) throw new ProtocolException(1045);

    return Cache::get($slug);
}
```