# PHP Attempting to invoke a serialized / encoded anonymous function within a class method returns 'Method name must be a string'

Tags: php, oop, anonymous-function

I have a class within which I want to

1. Set an array
2. Loop through the array
3. Invoke [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) set in #1 as I loop through the array in #2

EDIT: The code below is working when tested out of my application, but in my CodeIgniter 3 Controller, I keep getting an error: `Method name must be a string`

My simplified code for the purposes of example (CodeIgniter 3):

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    // Setting my array
    public function my_arr ($options = array())
    {
        $arr = array(
            '1' => array(
                'a' => 'z',
                'b' => function($i) {
                    return 'c' . $i;
                },
            ),
            '2' => array(
                'a' => 'y',
                'b' => function($i) {
                    return 'd' . $i;
                },
            ),
        );

        return $arr;
        /**
         *
         * EDIT: Later in my code I found that there was some kind
         * of serialization/encoding attempt like:              
         * json_decode(json_encode($arr));
         */

    }

    // Doing My Loop
    public function do_loop()
    {
        $my_arr = $this->my_arr();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($my_arr as $key => $value){
            $anonymous_function = $value['b'];
            echo $anonymous_function($i) . '<br>'; // Keep getting `Method name must be a string`
            $i++;
        }
    }

}

(new MyClass())->do_loop();
```

Comment: This code should never enter the loop at all, `my_arr()` doesn't return anything here. It also has invalid syntax. In this particular case you should provide with an example that is reproducible. Fixing those two issues I can't reproduce your problem at https://3v4l.org/2vLRs

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos . I fixed my mistakes / updated the code

Comment: I still cannot reproduce your problem https://onlinephp.io/c/2e92c

Comment: Thanks again @apokryfos . After a bit more digging, I found that the issue had to do with serialization / encoding. I've updated my original question & title for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Posting back here in hopes that it helps.

My issue:

- Later on in my codebase, I was trying to encode/serialize my method's
  output.
- After a bit of reading, I found out that `json_encode()` &
  `serialize()` don't support [serialization of closures / anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734224/exception-serialization-of-closure-is-not-allowed/19730234#19730234).
- So, the `Method name must be a string` error happend because my attempts to encode/serialize - effectively - stripped the anonymous functions out & thus referenced a null function.

How I resolved the issue:

- First I started with [Opis Closure](https://github.com/opis/closure) library to seralize the closure (I didn't end up going with this, but including it because I think it's a pretty cool library)
- After the above, I just realized that I should refactor so that I wasn't trying serialize closures at all.